# PHP: x-sendfile for litespeed

Tags: php, x-sendfile, litespeed

I use below code for apache :

```
$file = 'a.mp3';
$mime = mime_content_type($file);
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);
exit();
```

But new server manager asked me change it to litespeed version

How ?

Comment: it might works give a try :   header('X-LiteSpeed-Location:' . $file);

Comment: @Peter thank you, i change to it, but not work

Comment: What error you are getting after using above code?

Comment: @Peter i add / and fixed it : `$file = '/a.mp3';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

```
$file = 'https://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4';
$mime = 'video/mp4';
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
// header('X-Sendfile: ' . $file);
header('X-LiteSpeed-Location:' . $file);

exit();
```

Comment: Thank you, if i want force download video, how i can ? your code play direct on browser, but i want download it without play

Comment: @ComputerIm to force download, try `header("Content-Disposition: attachment");`

Comment: According to [this](https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:config:internal-redirect) you also need a `Location` header and use the url without the protocol and domain parts. And don't forget you shouldn't send a `status`